# What is the 'safe zone' in the lost woods?

Tags: zelda-breath-of-the-wild

I was wondering, when traversing the lost woods in Breath of The Wild, how far can you go off course before the games voids you out?

Especially in that second part where they give you a torch and you are on your own, I really wonder how it looks like from  birds-eye view of how far off-course you can be before getting reset to the last checkpoint?

Comment: Relephant: [Stand still and look at the embers flying off the top of the torch. They will be blowing slightly in the direction you need to go.](https://www.ign.com/wikis/the-legend-of-zelda-breath-of-the-wild/How_to_Get_Through_the_Lost_Woods) - It doesn't exactly answer the question asked, but this is used as a guide (TIL!)

Comment: Yeah, thats how you beat it. But I really wonder how far can you go off course before the game voids you out.

Comment: You can check this if you have the DLC  "Master Trials" which introduce the Hero Path feature, showing your path during the last 200 hours of play. This can be used to repeatedly reach the border of the accessible zone (until you are teleported back) and then the zone will appear in green on the map when activating hero path. A little bit time-consuming, though, so I may leave to other the task to actually perform it.

Comment: True. I would have to boot up Botw to test it lol

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at [savage13's 3D object map](https://restite.org/3dmap/). Click the ⚙ in the top left corner and tick `Korok Forest Fog`.

Comment: Activating that and the 'Locations' marker really helps. Its a lot less complex than i tought lol, its basically a rectangle with a small gate at the end. so you can get lost for a while, there is not a lot of chances you luck into the exit.

Answer (score 4):

The answer is: **not much**. As soon as you walk a few steps in the wrong direction you'll be reset. In some cases you can prevent this by immediately running in the right direction as soon as the mist starts to increase, but you have less than a second to prevent this condition and avoid being reset to the start.

Comment: Yeah in the part where you follow preset torches seems to be corridors that are pretty much on a grid, and if you leave the corridor you get voided. I mostly wonder the part where you are given a torch and kinda free flowing